# Xamarin Forms resize grid animation in MVVM

Tags: c#, xamarin, animation, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I can't figure it out **how make a simple animation where after the click of a button a grid element changes it's size**.
I work with **MVVM** so, like WPF if it's possible I prefere a "**full xaml**" solution (in my head a simple animation is charged to the view and not to the viewModel).

How can i do it?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you are looking for something like below.

https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/Xamanimation#progress-animations

If not, please refer to the below documentation links for details about Animation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/simple

You can also write your own custom animations in Xamarin. Please refer below links.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/animation/custom

Answer (score 2):

In Xaml you should bind your Button into the CommandParameter. To do this, 
Step 1 - Give a x:name, step 2 bind it

```
 <Button Command="{Binding MyButtonCommand}"
                x:Name="myButton"
                CommandParameter="{Binding  Source={x:Reference myButton}}"/>
```

In your ViewModel:

```
 public ICommand MyButtonCommand=> new Command(async(o) =>
        {
            Button myButton = (Button)o;
            await myButton.TranslateTo(50, 0, 400);
        });
```

Comment: This is even a good idea but in this way the ViewModel is aware of components of the View (of course the compromise is always possible and it's not necessary to be an MVVM purist) but a total xaml solution is better for my project. Thank you